# How to get Netty to serve / accept websocket from web-app served on different server ('node') on different port

Tags: websocket, netty

I am playing around with a websocket in Angular 7 webapp. The idea is to have the web-app served by 'node' - e.g on address:

```
http://localhost:4200/
```

and websocket on another address and port served by Netty / Java app.

On the web-app I navigate to a page of a websocket. There is a textbox for entering the address of the websocket and button: 'Connect' - that connects us to the web-socket server. Test to this address for example works fine:

```
ws://echo.websocket.org          // works - we get a response
or
ws://echo.websocket.org:80       // works - we get a response
```

Instead, I want to get Netty server to serve the websocket. I start the server - serves on address:

```
http://localhost:8081/
```

and runs fine. (I  can connect from a separate browser window and the websocket page served by the server on this address and port).

But now I want to connect to the Netty server from my web-app on - localhost:4200/. So, I provide this address for the socket connection;

```
ws://localhost:8081/
```

and click 'Connect'.

The Netty server reacts with this log (all lines appear at the same time):

```
Feb 16, 2019 7:26:20 AM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelRead
INFO: [id: 0xfd77a1f7, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8081] READ: [id: 0x24ad1bc1, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:51928]
Feb 16, 2019 7:26:20 AM io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler channelReadComplete
INFO: [id: 0xfd77a1f7, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8081] READ COMPLETE
Websocke channel Active:[id: 0x24ad1bc1, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 - R:/127.0.0.1:51928]
Websocke channel Inactive:[id: 0x24ad1bc1, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 ! R:/127.0.0.1:51928]
Websocke channel Unregistered:[id: 0x24ad1bc1, L:/127.0.0.1:8081 ! R:/127.0.0.1:51928]
```

This likely means the communication works, however, Netty is not accepting and is taking the websocket down.

These are my handlers in the Netty pipeline:

```
    new HttpServerCodec());
    new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
    new WebSocketServerCompressionHandler());
    new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler(WEBSOCKET_PATH, null, true));
              // Next handler serves index.html page
              //   ... extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest>
              //       @Override
              //      protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest req) throws Exception {
    new WebSocketIndexPageHandlerA1(WEBSOCKET_PATH));
              // Next handler handles websocket communication
              //   ... extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<WebSocketFrame>
              //       @Override
              //      protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, WebSocketFrame frame) {
    new WebSocketFrameHandlerA1());
```

How do we get Netty to accept this websocket request and pass the flow down the pipeline to my last handler - web socket message handler - WebSocketFrameHandlerA1 so it can reply to the websocket client(s) - wherever they come from ?

Answer (score 0):

This question has a fairly straight forward and logical answer. We simply need to equip our Netty's pipeline wit handlers corresponding to the expected traffic (HTTP/Websockets, etc.) from the client(s).

So, if we try to connect to Netty using:

```
ws://localhost:8081/
```

the server will receive an initial HTTP request - something like this:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: XVXVXS%GDDD+lDfDS==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1146780314.5634479786
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Connection : keep-alive, Upgrade
Upgrade : websocket
```

We must make sure we have the proper handlers in the pipeline, to handle the initial HTTP request and then upgrade/switch to the websocket handler. In this case the initial pipeline can be as simple as this:

```
pipeline.addLast("httpServerCodec", new HttpServerCodec());
pipeline.addLast("httpHandler", new HttpServerHandler());
```

Further in the HttpServerHandler include:

```
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

        if (msg instanceof HttpRequest) {

            HttpRequest httpRequest = (HttpRequest) msg;
            HttpHeaders headers = httpRequest.headers();

            if (headers.get(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION).toUpperCase().contains("UPGRADE") &&
            headers.get(HttpHeaderNames.UPGRADE).toUpperCase().contains("WEBSOCKET")) {

                // Replace the HTTP handler with a websocket handler
                // in the existing pipeline to handle WebSocket Messages
                ctx.pipeline().replace(this, "websocketHandler", new WebSocketHandler());
                //Do the Handshake to upgrade connection from HTTP to WebSocket protocol
            handleHandshake(ctx, httpRequest);
        }
        ...
      }
```

In your websocket handler insert the logic of the data exchange between the client and server.